# Using XLForm's in Swift with a Bridge Header

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I've been trying to XLForms in Swift using a bridge header as they suggest.

I've loaded the XLForms Pod and added the bridge file and referenced it in Swift Compiler. The Bridge file references includes `#import <XLForm/XLForm.h>`.

However, when I try and compile my project I get

> Use of undeclared type 'XLFormViewController'

I assume that means it Swift hasn't got access to the library.

I've tried different versions and attempting the setup again, but I can't seem to get it to find it. If I change `#import <XLForm/XLForm.h>` to `#import <XLForm.h>` Xcode warns me that it can't find the file, so I know that Xcode is finding it with `#import <XLForm/XLForm.h>` .. just not allowing me to use it.

Any suggestions?

EDIT: I've tried including another library and I'm experiencing the same issue. Are there any other steps to using the Bridge Header?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using

```
import XLForm
```

Resolved the problem.